# SQL Query in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

I have four tables that I want to join and display the output all together. I'm not sure how the syntax works for Oracle SQL Developer. I know this is an easy question for a programmer and I was hoping someone can make a suggestion on how the code might look like.

The tables are tables are: JNL1 JNL2 JNL3 JNL4

```
JNL1
JNL2
JNL3
JNL4
```

I only want to display the results with UserCode=Automation and the Date to be one day before the current one.  The code for that is:

```
  UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,LEFT(DATE,8))=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112)
```

The keys that are common between all four of these tables is ItemID, Date, and UserCode.

I'm not sure how the query will look like, I can generate the joining tables query and the UserCode/Date query as separate queries.  But when I combine them into one query I either get errors on ambiguous column name, or the query runs with no data being displayed from the database.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, expected results, and the code that you have tried?  Also, the query is tagged "oracle" but it is using SQL Server syntax in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Don't join the tables.
as you require to get the data from only one table and table structure are same then you can have multiple `unions`

-- In oracle database you can not have column name as date, I am assuming that `date` column name is c_date-

```
select ItemID, c_Date, and UserCode
from Jul1
where UserCode = 'Automation' 
  AND c_date = trunc(sysdate) -1
union all 
select ItemID, c_Date, and UserCode
from Jul2
where UserCode = 'Automation' 
  AND c_date = trunc(sysdate) -1
union all 
select ItemID, c_Date, and UserCode
from Jul3
where UserCode = 'Automation' 
  AND c_date = trunc(sysdate) -1
union all 
select ItemID, c_Date, and UserCode
from Jul4
where UserCode = 'Automation' 
  AND c_date = trunc(sysdate) -1
```

*`sysdate` is system function which will return the current date with time value.

Comment: How would the code look like if I wanted all the columns from each table, not just ItemID, c_Date, and UserCode?

Comment: @KJ .. please tell .. how you require all the column from all the tables?

as your table name shows that these tables stored data for respective dates.. and you want to fetch only the yesterday's data .. in that case how you would fetch data from other three tables?